# Access interface of return value of enclosedElement in java annotationprocessor using TypeVisitor?

Tags: java, annotation-processing

I'm currently building an annotation processor, and I want to filter all methods that return a record that implement a certain interface.

In the IntelliJ Debug window I can see that the restype variable has an interfaces_field where I can get the classtype  of the return value.

[image: IntelliJ Debug Window]

I would like to to access this value at build time, but I run into this error when accessing the restype directly like I do in the expression window:

```
e: file:///home/thomas/IdeaProjects/spring-view-component/core/src/main/kotlin/de/tschuehly/spring/viewcomponent/core/processor/ViewComponentProcessor.kt:3:33 
Symbol is declared in module 'jdk.compiler' which does not export package 'com.sun.tools.javac.code'
```

The next issue is that I don't know how to access the interfaces_field attribute in the restype value.

I think the solution would be a [TypeVisitor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/type/TypeVisitor.html), but I didn't find any examples with my Google fu.

Someone knows how to this?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't quite clear to me what you're asking - your groovy(?) code in the expression window appears to filter methods and return their method typemirrors (i.e. a list of `javax.lang.model.type.ExecutableType`).

If so, you can call `ExecutableType.getReturnType()` on each instance, then verify that the returned type is a `DeclaredType` (and not a primitive, or array, typevariable, etc). `DeclaredType` doesn't give access directly to its implemented interfaces either, but that probably only matters if you need the generic args passed to the interface. If not, you can just call `DeclaredType.asElement()` to get the `TypeElement` (now an element instead of a mirror), and then call `TypeElement.getInterfaces()` on that to get the directly implemented interfaces - note that you'll need to visit the superclass and any other interfaces recursively to pick up transitively implemented interfaces.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll take a look if I can get it working!